# Error when creating an XNA project

Tags: xna, visual-studio-templates

I've just installed XNA Game Studio 4. But when I create a new XNA project, I get an error:

> "Code/XnaWindowsGeme.vstemplate" was not found.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the file extension and the context in which the error appeared, Visual Studio seems to be failing in looking up the template associated with an XNA Windows Game Project. My guess is that the XNA installer somehow failed to install this template to your Visual Studio instance. Possibly due to multiple instances/versions of Visual Studio installed. You could also try reinstalling XNA.